# Wi-fi suddenly does not connect on Ubuntu 22.04. Authentication times out

Tags: wireless, 22.04, mediatek

I have an ASUS laptop dual-booted with Ubuntu 22.04. I booted it up today and the wifi ssid shows up but it never connects.`dmesg` shows the authentication times out. Tried connecting to the same wifi with another device and there is no problem at that end.
I tried solutions suggested throughout the web and reached nowhere. Here is the current state of the network side of my system. Let me know if there is something that I missed.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 12 Apr 2023 17:26 CEST +0200

Booted last: 12 Apr 2023 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

##### kernel ############################

Linux 6.2.10-060210-generic #202304061139 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  6 11:45:43 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /root/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7961]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:4680]
    Kernel driver in use: mt7921e

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 3277:0010 Sonix Technology Co., Ltd. USB2.0 FHD UVC WebCam
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 13d3:3563 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2808:a658 Realtek USB2.0 Finger Print Bridge FocalTech Fingerprint Device
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:0409 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.2 Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0b00:0409 INGENICO USB3.2 Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone 5/5C/5S/6/SE
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0bda:1101 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HID Device
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:5418 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. BillBoard Device
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:c00c Dell Computer Corp. Integrated_Webcam_5M_IR
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:c00b Dell Computer Corp. C2422HE
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0bda:1100 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HID Device
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. Dell MS116 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. KB216 Wired Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5409 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB2.1 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b00:5409 INGENICO USB2.1 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

mac80211             1617920  3 mt76,mt7921_common,mt76_connac_lib
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
asus_wmi               73728  1 asus_nb_wmi
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,asus_wmi
cfg80211             1241088  4 mt76,mac80211,mt7921_common,mt76_connac_lib
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
platform_profile       16384  1 asus_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
video                  69632  3 asus_wmi,amdgpu,nvidia_modeset
wmi                    40960  3 video,asus_wmi,wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
4: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether <MAC 'docker0' [IF3]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: enx<IF from MAC [IF4]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF4]>' [IF4]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 172.20.10.4/28 brd 172.20.10.15 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx<IF from MAC [IF4]>
       valid_lft 85709sec preferred_lft 85709sec
    inet6 fe80::68dc:9f74:db48:ca6/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

enx<IF from MAC [IF4]>  no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=3 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          

##### route #############################

default via 172.20.10.1 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF4]> proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev docker0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.20.10.0/28 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF4]> proto kernel scope link src 172.20.10.4 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         744       1  0 17:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         docker0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBridge
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bridge
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'docker0' [IF3]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected (externally))
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/virtual/net/docker0
GENERAL.PATH:                           --
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       docker0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    yes
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     docker0
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       d2dc9c99-ef8f-4968-94cc-37212b00ed87
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               yes
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.17.0.1/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 172.17.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
BRIDGE.SLAVES:                          --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/12
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   d2dc9c99-ef8f-4968-94cc-37212b00ed87 | docker0

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         MEDIATEK Corp.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         mt7921e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.2.10-060210-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               ____010000-20220209150915
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:02:00.0/net/wlan0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:02:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   unknown
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   unknown
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               no
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/5
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   7ea2b277-2f4d-4c39-925c-ca2b7646b597 | kleso-ap-3931672 1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         cdc_ncm
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.2.10-060210-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               CDC NCM (NO ZLP)
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.3/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:2.0/net/enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:04:00.3-usb-0:1.2:2.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID              BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE 
kleso-ap-3931672  <MAC 'kleso-ap-3931672' [AN1]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  65 Mbit/s  85      ▂▄▆█  WPA2      no             
AP_1607161311     <MAC 'AP_1607161311' [AN2]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  65 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  --        no             
kleso1C59765      <MAC 'kleso1C59765' [AN3]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  65 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA2      no             
BryantPark        <MAC 'BryantPark' [AN4]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  65 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA2      no             
kleso26C18D3      <MAC 'kleso26C18D3' [AN5]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  65 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA2      no             
kleso6489313      <MAC 'kleso6489313' [AN6]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  65 Mbit/s  39      ▂▄__  WPA2      no             

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.backend=iwd

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### dmesg #############################

[   11.022179] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address>
[   11.190418] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[   11.225442] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address> (try 2/3)
[   11.260470] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address> (try 3/3)
[   11.293152] wlan0: authentication with <MAC address> timed out
[   68.665062] ipheth 1-4:4.2 enx<IF from MAC [IF4]>: renamed from eth0
[   69.827935] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx<IF from MAC [IF4]>: link becomes ready
[   97.584637] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'kleso-ap-3931672' [AC6]>
[   97.604572] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'kleso-ap-3931672' [AC6]> (try 1/3)
[   97.612044] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'kleso-ap-3931672' [AC6]> (try 2/3)
[   97.619362] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'kleso-ap-3931672' [AC6]> (try 3/3)
[   97.626592] wlan0: authentication with <MAC 'kleso-ap-3931672' [AC6]> timed out
[  101.733999] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address>
[  101.753486] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[  101.789269] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address> (try 2/3)
[  101.822131] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address> (try 3/3)
[  101.856211] wlan0: authentication with <MAC address> timed out
[  314.104170] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'kleso-ap-3931672' [AC6]>
[  314.122354] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'kleso-ap-3931672' [AC6]> (try 1/3)
[  314.129927] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'kleso-ap-3931672' [AC6]> (try 2/3)
[  314.137394] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'kleso-ap-3931672' [AC6]> (try 3/3)
[  314.144998] wlan0: authentication with <MAC 'kleso-ap-3931672' [AC6]> timed out

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: There is no version of Ubuntu that currently uses the 6.2 kernel as a supported kernel. Why are you running this test kernel?

Comment: Many suggestions on this forum indicated that I might need to update my kernel to appease the driver. However, saw no improvement.